# Can't install specific library cryptography in Python 3 using Pip

Tags: python, pip

I am inside a corporate internet that uses proxy

I run the command

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.python hosted.org --proxy=http://721094:Fafafa51..@proxy.pucminas.br:80 flask_restful
```

and it works perfectly, but when I try to run

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.python hosted.org --proxy=http://721094:Fafafa51..@proxy.pucminas.br:80 cryptography
```

I got an error:

```
HTTP error 403 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/c0/e46342325e9d1faf2d3d8b12acadb527e283a5cd4455dc95d98f453df876/cryptography-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=b0833d27c7eb536bc27323a1e8e22cb39ebac78c4ef3be0167ba40f447344808 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cryptography/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*)
Could not install requirement cryptography from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/c0/e46342325e9d1faf2d3d8b12acadb527e283a5cd4455dc95d98f453df876/cryptography-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=b0833d27c7eb536bc27323a1e8e22cb39ebac78c4ef3be0167ba40f447344808 because of error 403 Client Error: MediaTypeBlocked for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/c0/e46342325e9d1faf2d3d8b12acadb527e283a5cd4455dc95d98f453df876/cryptography-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

How can if fix this?

Is it strange because I was able to install some libraries, but it was not possible install cryptography library

I use some code that needs cryptography library, but it won't install for me

My python version is 3.6.6.1

Comment: Did you ask your sysadmin or the proxy owner?

Comment: No, because I can't contact the sysadmin directly. The last time that I try, it took more than three months to get answer from him.

Comment: I try to put the following url in my browser "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/c0/e46342325e9d1faf2d3d8b12acadb527e283a5cd4455dc95d98f453df876/cryptography-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" and the content is blocked by sysadmin. I think my only option is to contact the sysadmin.